# Получить UTM в android

Tags: android, playmarket

Столкнулся с проблемой что Плей Маркет не отдает utm после установки прилы. Делал все по туториалу по получению utm через reciver - тесты все отрабатывают и ресивер срабатывает. Но если залить на прод прилу и юзер установит с рекламы именно в play market, а не с сайта или поиска в гугле (естественно с рекламы), то ресивер после установки не срабатывает. Я так понимаю utm будет передаваться только если юзер установит приложение по рекламной ссылке с сайта или поиска. Если ли вообще возможность получать utm когда юзер устанавливает приложение по рекламе внутри Маркета?

Comment: Попробовал библеотеку com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2, она вытягивает при установки campaign - goole-play. Теперь вопрос стоит - будет ли она вытягивать utm нормально или все так же как и с ресивером будет? Очень интересная тема - нигде нет внятного ответа вот и задал этот вопрос здесь)